# How can I remove smart search list group when the input string has a value first, then has empty string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently looking for advice on how to handle this. I'm not sure if I should be adding a flag in application state or if this can be handled in the component. Also, I'm not sure what event I can use to capture this condition. I have added a youtube video of the bug below.
[Search Bug | Ryan](https://youtu.be/fJd9hG8UcEs)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Search extends Component {

// this block is added to attempt to reset the list group
listReset = true;

handleSearchTerm(term) {
    if (!term == "") {
        this.props.getSearchResults({term});
        this.listReset = false;
    } else {
        this.listReset = true
    }
}
// end

buildResultsList() {
    if (!this.props.searchResults) {
        return null;
    } else {
        const searchResultsList = this.props.searchResults.map(function (result) {
            return (
                <li key={result.urlName} className="list-group-item">{result.urlName}</li>
            );
        });
        return searchResultsList;
    }
}


render() {
    console.log(this.props.searchResults);

    return (
        <div className="search-component">
            <form className="form-inline nav-search ">
                <input
                    className="form-control mr-sm-2 dropdown-toggle"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                    id="navBarSearchForm"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="What are you looking for?"
                    autoComplete="off">
                </input>
            </form>
            <ul className="list-group search-results">
                {this.listReset == false ? this.buildResultsList() : null}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}


}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return { searchResults: state.search.searchResult};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Search);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this:

```
handleSearchTerm(term) {
    if (!term == "") {
        this.props.getSearchResults({term});
        this.displayResultsController(true);
    } else {
        this.displayResultsController(false);
    }
}

displayResultsController(display) {
    if (display === true) {
        $( ".search-results" ).css( "display", "block" );
    } else {
        $( ".search-results" ).css( "display", "none" );
    }
}
```

and changed to this

```
<ul className="list-group search-results">
                {this.buildResultsList()}
            </ul>
```